# Constant gcc.exe: error: mario.c: No such file or directory error on vscode when trying to run C file

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc, mingw

I've been looking for an answer for around 2 hours now and can'tfind anything that works. My code is a very simple Hello World code.

The complete error is:

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\C_Projects\mario> cd "c:\Windows\System32\C_Projects\mario\" ; if ($?) { gcc mario.c -o mario } ; if ($?) { .\mario }
gcc.exe: error: mario.c: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

So far I've edited my `c_cpp_properties.json` file to include a compilerpath to my MinGW\bin\gcc.exe compiler, might be the wrong one though I'm not sure.

Does anyone have a clue on how to solve this issue and get my code to run? I can't find an answer that works for me on any other post.

Comment: It is unlikely that the `C_Projects` folder is in the `c:\Windows\System32` folder. Your Visual Studio Code configuration is wrong. But as long as you don't show your `c_cpp_properties.json` file, it's hard to help. Please [edit].